# Run atexit() when python process is killed

Tags: python, background-process, atexit

I have a python process which runs in background, and I would like it to generate some output only when the script is terminated.

```
def handle_exit():
    print('\nAll files saved in ' + directory)
    generate_output()

atexit.register(handle_exit)
```

Calling raising a `KeyboardInterupt` exception and `sys.exit()` calls `handle_exit()` properly, but if I were to do `kill {PID}` from the terminal it terminates the script without calling handle_exit().

Is there a way to terminate the process that is running in the background, and still have it run `handle_exit()` before terminating?

Comment: Not possible with atexit alone. As the documentation states `The functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called.` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try [signal.signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html?#signal.signal). It allows to catch any system signal:

```
import signal

def handle_exit():
    print('\nAll files saved in ' + directory)
    generate_output()

atexit.register(handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)
```

Now you can `kill {pid}` and `handle_exit` will be executed.

Comment: N.B., your handler function signatures should afford two positional arguments – a signal number and a stack frame, e.g. `handle_exit(signum, frame)` or `handle_exit(*args)` – as that’s how those functions invoked via `signal.signal(…)` will be called. If your functions take explicit arguments, you can set up values for `atexit.register(…)` to pass on its own invocation, e.g. `atexit.register(handle_exit, None, None)` or similar.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows when closing via Task Manager or via Stop button in PyCharm

Comment: This will execute `handle_exit` _twice_ - once from handle_exit and _then again_ from atexit.register.

Answer (score 1):

To enable signals when debugging PyCharm on Windows:

1. Within PyCharm hit `Ctrl + Shift + A` to bring up the "Find Actions..." menu
2. Search for "Registry" and hit enter
3. Find the key `kill.windows.processes.softly` and enable it (you can start typing "kill" and it will search for the key)
4. Restart PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

To check your system and see which signal is being called:

```
import signal
import time


def handle_signal(sig_id, frame):
    sig = {x.value: x for x in signal.valid_signals()}.get(sig_id)
    print(f'{sig.name}, {sig_id=}, {frame=}')
    exit(-1)


for sig in signal.valid_signals():
    print(f'{sig.value}: signal.{sig.name},')
    signal.signal(sig, handle_signal)

time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle signals yourself, according to the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/signal.html#signal.signal), the handler function needs two arguments.

If you handle the SIGINT signal, you must call `sys.exit(0)` within the handler function; otherwise, the program will not terminate upon pressing `Ctrl + C`.

As KamiCuk mentioned, if the function registered with atexit is the same as the signal handler function, the function will be called twice.

Therefore, I prefer using separate functions for the signal handler and for the atexit registration. Here is an example:

```py
import atexit
import signal
import sys

def on_exit():
    print('real clean code here')

def handle_exit(signum, frame):
    sys.exit(0)

atexit.register(on_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)
```

Handling these signals correctly can be tricky, especially for cross-platform applications.

To address this, I have created a package called [safe-exit](https://pypi.org/project/safe-exit/).

The documentation can be found here: https://safe-exit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/